# Instance variable heap or stack ? ( with specific example)

Tags: java, stack, instance, heap-memory

With the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A objectA = new A();
        objectA.deleteB();
    }
}

public class A {

    private B objectB;

    public A() {
        this.objectB = new B();
    }

    public void deleteB() {
       this.objectB = null;
    }
}

public class B {
   public B() {}
}
```

The first frame in the stack is for main()

with local variable objectA  in the stack that contain reference to real Object A in the heap and in Object A in the heap we have a reference Object B pointing the real Object B also in the heap.

The question is for the second frame in the stack deleteB()

In the method I do: this.objectB = null;

what does it mean in the memory ?

Comment: It clears `A`'s reference to `B`. What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the `objectB` field of `objectA` no longer references anything. If the object (on the heap) it was referencing before is not referenced anywhere else (and it isn't in the code you posted), it will be garbage collected. This means that the memory it was occupying on the heap will be deallocated, and can be used for other objects.

Comment: In the heap we have ObjectA that containt a ObjectB with a reference value in it pointing the real ObjectB, but it is in the heap.
Then when we come to deleteB in the stack, do we create a variable with a reference to ObjectB ? or a variable with a reference to ObjectA ?

I mean, I am confuse about my mind representation of the thing here :/

Comment: What does "deleteB in the stack" mean?   All that is relevant here is that first you execute ```something = new B()``` and then ```something = null```, for the exact same 'something'.

Comment: it mean that what I understood is each time a method is call, a new frame is create in the stack and memory space is create to store a value that contain primitive value or reference value. What I want to know here is: when a frame is created because of the call of deleteB method, is a reference value pointing Object B is created in the stack or not ^^

Comment: @AnthonyBehi nothing is created in the stack when deleteB is called - there are no local variables declared inside of it

Comment: @mangusta ok thank you, I will read more documentation because what I thought was wrong